# Pandas calculate hourly rolling mean

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My dataset `df` looks like this. It is a `minute` based dataset.

```
time, Open, High
2017-01-01 00:00:00, 1.2432, 1.1234
2017-01-01 00:01:00, 1.2432, 1.1234
2017-01-01 00:02:00, 1.2332, 1.1234
2017-01-01 00:03:00, 1.2132, 1.1234
...., ...., ....
2017-12-31 23:59:00, 1.2132, 1.1234
```

I want to find the hourly `rolling mean` for `Open` column but should be flexible so that I can also find hourly `rolling mean` for other columns.

What did I do?

I am able to find the `daily rolling average` like given below, but how do I find for the hour basis so that I do not find `mean` for the entire day

```
# Pandas code to find the rolling mean for a single day

df
.assign(1davg=df.rolling(window=1*24*60)['Open'].mean()) 
.groupby(df['time'].dt.date) 
.last()
```

Please note that changing this line of code does not work because I already tried it: `window=1*24*60` to `window=60`

Comment: do you want to ignore all rows for which `time` doesn't fall into [22:01, 00:02] interval?

Comment: So it is basically `hourly` `avg` but I do not want `avg` for all the hours. So I want to only load and save `avg` for a specific time frame

Comment: @MaxU I just updated the question for clarity and simplicity, please kindly review the question.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
mask = (df["time"].dt.hour >= 22) | (df["time"].dt.hour <= 2)   
res = df.loc[mask].rolling("1H", on="time")["Open"].mean()
```

Comment: I just updated the question for clarity and simplicity, please kindly review the question.