# Pandas find hourly rolling average

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime, python-datetime

My dataset `df` looks like this. It is a `minute` based dataset.

```
time, Open, High
2017-01-01 00:00:00, 1.2432, 1.1234
2017-01-01 00:01:00, 1.2432, 1.1234
2017-01-01 00:02:00, 1.2332, 1.1234
2017-01-01 00:03:00, 1.2132, 1.1234
...., ...., ....
2017-12-31 23:59:00, 1.2132, 1.1234
```

I want to find the hourly `rolling mean` for `Open` column but it should be flexible so that I can also find hourly `rolling mean` for other columns.

What did I do?

I am able to find the `daily rolling average` like given below:

```
# Pandas code to find the rolling mean for a single day

df
.assign(1davg=df.rolling(window=1*24*60)['Open'].mean()) 
.groupby(df['time'].dt.date) 
.last()
```

Please note that changing this(`window=1*24*60` to `window=60`) line of code does not work because I already tried it.

The new `output` should look like this:

```
time,                 Open,  High,   Open_hour_avg
2017-01-01 00:00:00, 1.2432, 1.1234,   1.2532
2017-01-01 01:00:00, 1.2432, 1.1234,   1.2632    
2017-01-01 02:00:00, 1.2332, 1.1234,   1.2332
2017-01-01 03:00:00, 1.2132, 1.1234,   1.2432
...., ...., ...., ....
2017-12-31 23:00:00, 1.2132, 1.1234,   1.2232
```

here,

`2017-01-01 00:00:00, 1.2432, 1.1234,   1.2532` is the `minute` average data for `midnight`

and `2017-01-01 01:00:00, 1.2432, 1.1234, 1.2632` is the `minute` average data for `1 AM`

Comment: Did you try resampling the time series hourly?  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Comment: I tried that but it is giving `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex` but my `df` is already in `DatetimeIndex`

Comment: try: df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index) and than try resampling

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas calculate hourly rolling mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57047013/pandas-calculate-hourly-rolling-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I got it working:

```
import pandas as pd

# After your CSV data is in a df

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df.index = df['time']
df_mean = df.resample('H').mean()


time,                 Open       High   
2017-01-01 00:00:00 1.051488    1.051500     
2017-01-01 01:00:00 1.051247    1.051275     
2017-01-01 02:00:00 1.051890    1.051957     
2017-01-01 03:00:00 1.051225    1.051290     
...., ...., ....
2017-12-31 23:00:00 1.051225    1.051290
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
df['open_ave_hour']=df.groupby(df.time.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')).Open.mean().reindex(df.time.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')).to_numpy()
```

Or transform

```
df['open_ave_hour']=df.groupby(df.time.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')).Open.transform('mean')
```